# jQuery listener click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, listener

So I have this code that *should* listen for a click on #button but it won't work, and is driving me crazy!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert('OK!');
    });
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="OK" />
```

This is strange. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Write your code inside document.ready function

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        alert('OK!');
    });
});
</script>


 OR
<script type="text/javascript">
    function on_click() {
          alert("OK !!");
    }
    $(document).ready(function() { 
         $("#button").click(on_click);
    });
</script>
```

hope you get some idea from this

Comment: can I apply this logic to a whole 'functions.js' file?

Comment: yeah you can apply that inside the js file too

Comment: Tried wrapping everything inside my functions document in $(document).ready(function() { FUNCTIONS etc });

Won't work.

Comment: dont wrap the function .. function are written outside the document.ready.. only your logic are written inside the ready .. i will update my code little bit

Comment: Okay thank you. I was hoping for something I could add to bulk code because I have quite a few listeners that stopped working recently so...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the code should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // Now that jquery is include, place the code to wire up the button here
    $(function(){
        // Once the document.onload event fires, attach the click
        // event handler for the button
        $('#button').click(function() { 
            alert('OK!'); 
        });
    });
</script> 
<input id="button" type="button" value="OK" />
```

Here's the jquery documentation that relates to this:
http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Up-voting this as it contains a better explanation of why the original code did not work and points to details on how $(function() {}); works.

Comment: Just a little suggestion, `.click(function)(){` won't fire on touch devices, for that, you could use `.on('click', function () {`

Comment: @Hackinet Actually `.click(function(){` is just a short hand for `.on('click', function() {` so they will work exactly the same.